# I need data for all 24 months of data even with missing months

Tags: sql, oracle

I need data for all 24 months of data even with missing months.

sample data

```
 id     custname    reportdate   sales
 1        xx        31-JAN-17    1256
 1        xx        31-MAR-17    3456
 1        xx        30-JUN-17    5678
 1        xx        31-DEC-17    6785
 2        xx        31-JAN-17    1223
 2        xx        31-APR-17    3435
 2        xx        30-JUN-17    6777
 2        xx        31-DEC-17    9643
```

what i need as a output

```
 id     custname    reportdate   sales
 1        xx        JAN-17       1256 
 1        xx        FEB-17       <null>
 1        xx        MAR-17       3456
 .....................................
 .....................................
 1        xx        DEC-17       6785
```

And similarly for id 2 ....

Tried something like this without any luck

```
select CUSTNAME, reportdate, sales from
(
select TRIM( LEADING '0' FROM TO_CHAR( statementdate, 'YYYY-MM') ) AS REPORTDATE mm, CUSTNAME
froM MYTABLE) SALES,
(
select to_char(date '2017-01-01' + numtoyminterval(level,'month'), 'mm') MonthName
--i actually need format as MON-Last 2 digit of year eg:JAN-17
from dual
connect by level <= 24) ALLMONTHS
where mm = MonthName(+)
```

also tried with CTE and i cant use my_year.year_month CTE with outer join

```
my_year as (
       select date '2017-01-31' start_date,date '2018-12-31' end_date from dual
          )
   select  (to_char(add_months(trunc(start_date,'mm'),level - 1),'yyyy')||'-'||(to_char(add_months(trunc(start_date,'mm'),level - 1),'mm'))) year_month
     from  my_year
   connect by trunc(end_date,'mm') >= add_months(trunc(start_date,'mm'),level - 1);

select id, customername, reportdate, sales, 
TRIM( LEADING '0' FROM TO_CHAR( reportdate, 'YYYY-MM') ) AS stmntdate
from my_oracle_tbl a
where a.stmntdate = my_year.year_month (+)
```

also tried this as recommended by @Littlefoot, which isnt working

```
 WITH mydates AS (
    select LAST_DAY(add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1)) as mth, min_id,min_custname
  from (
  select min(id) as min_id, min(CUSTNAME) as min_custname
  from my_oracle_tbl 
  )
  connect by level <= 24)
  select
  nvl(t.id, a.min_id)id,
  nvl(t.CUSTNAME,a.min_custname)CUSTNAME, a.mth, t.sales
   from mydates a left join my_oracle_tbl t on a.mth= LAST_DAY(t.reporttdate)
  where
  t.id=2
```

;

Comment: Write a CTE that returns those 24 months. Outer join the result.

Comment: Thank you, Tried the below and i get error with my_year as (
       select date '2017-01-31' start_date,date '2018-12-31' end_date from dual
          )
   select  (to_char(add_months(trunc(start_date,'mm'),level - 1),'yyyy')||'-'||(to_char(add_months(trunc(start_date,'mm'),level - 1),'mm'))) year_month
     from  my_year
   connect by trunc(end_date,'mm') >= add_months(trunc(start_date,'mm'),level - 1);

select id, customername, reportdate, sales, 
TRIM( LEADING '0' FROM TO_CHAR( reportdate, 'YYYY-MM') ) AS stmntdate
from my_oracle_tbl a
where a.stmntdate = my_year.year_month

Comment: @Matthew McPeak  cant I use CTE here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example; see if it helps. It displays 12 months (you'd substitute it with 24 in line #21).

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (id, custname, reportdate, sales) as
  2        (select 1, 'xx', date '2017-01-31', 1256 from dual union all
  3         select 1, 'xx', date '2017-03-31', 3456 from dual union all
  4         select 1, 'xx', date '2017-06-30', 5678 from dual union all
  5         --
  6         select 2, 'xx', date '2017-03-31', 1223 from dual union all
  7         select 2, 'xx', date '2017-07-31', 3435 from dual union all
  8         select 2, 'xx', date '2017-09-30', 6777 from dual
  9        ),
 10      all_dates as
 11        (select add_months(min_repdate, column_value - 1) c_mon,
 12                min_id,
 13                min_custname
 14        from (select min(reportdate) min_repdate,
 15                     id min_id,
 16                     min(custname) min_custname
 17              from test
 18              group by id
 19             ),
 20             table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 21                                 connect by level <= 12
 22                                 ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 23       )
 24     select nvl(t.id, a.min_id) id,
 25            nvl(t.custname, a.min_custname) custname,
 26            a.c_mon,
 27            t.sales
 28     from all_dates a left join test t on a.min_id = t.id and a.c_mon = t.reportdate
 29     order by id, a.c_mon;

        ID CU C_MON           SALES
---------- -- ---------- ----------
         1 xx 31.01.2017       1256
         1 xx 28.02.2017
         1 xx 31.03.2017       3456
         1 xx 30.04.2017
         1 xx 31.05.2017
         1 xx 30.06.2017       5678
         1 xx 31.07.2017
         1 xx 31.08.2017
         1 xx 30.09.2017
         1 xx 31.10.2017
         1 xx 30.11.2017
         1 xx 31.12.2017
         2 xx 31.03.2017       1223
         2 xx 30.04.2017
         2 xx 31.05.2017
         2 xx 30.06.2017
         2 xx 31.07.2017       3435
         2 xx 31.08.2017
         2 xx 30.09.2017       6777
         2 xx 31.10.2017
         2 xx 30.11.2017
         2 xx 31.12.2017
         2 xx 31.01.2018
         2 xx 28.02.2018

24 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: can u guide on whats wrong with my above CTE query?

Comment: WITH factoring clause (or a CTE) doesn't create a table; you can use it only in the same query in which it is *declared*. It seems that you created a CTE named "my_year" (which does return 24 months), but then you used it in a separate query which doesn't know of "my_year".

Comment: The above query is not working when you have multiple dates in your union all, which is coming for our main table. I see you have constructed this union all for just one dates, but if we include different dates with different custid's and custnames then it is not yielding the results

Comment: My CTE uses data you posted while writing the question. I don't know what you really have unless you tell us so. Therefore, if input data is different, you should modify the question. Even better, you should create test case for us (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data). Because, you got what you asked for.

Comment: Sorry abt that i just modified my data. Just posted the query i used as per your recommendation, which isnt working

Comment: I modified query I previously posted. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some old school tricks (UNION ALL IN COMBINATION WITH ADD_MONTHS FUNCTION AND SUM):

```
select id, custname,month, 
decode(sum(sales),0,null,sum(sales)) sales from
(select id, custname,  to_char(reportdate, 'mon-rrrr') 
 month,sales from my_oracle_tbl  
 UNION ALL
 select a.*,b.*,0 sales from
 (select distinct id, custname from my_oracle_tbl) a, 
 (
      select to_char(sysdate,'mon')||'-2017' month from dual
      UNION ALL
      select ,to_char(add_months(sysdate,1),'mon')||'-2017' month from dual
      UNION ALL
      select ,to_char(add_months(sysdate,2),'mon')||'-2017' from dual
      .......
      UNION ALL
      select ,to_char(add_months(sysdate,11),'mon')||'-2017' from dual) b
 )
 group by id, custname,month;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with do u see any concerns? is there a better way to write this? I need to get order by lowest to largest dates?? how can i achieve this. As of now it repeats order like this 12-2018,12-2017,11-2018,11-2017. I want 2017 dates first and then 2018

```
select CUSTNAME, reportdate, sum(sales), mth
from (  select to_char(add_months(date '2017-01-01', level - 1), 'mmyyyy') mth 
  from dual 
  connect by level <= 24)mo
  left outer join oracle_tbl dc on mo.mth = to_char(reportdate, 'mmyyyy')
      group by CUSTNAME, reportdate,mth
    order by mth
```

Comment: @APC can you please chime here